# How to offset some table cells

Tags: html, css

I want to draw a table like the picture below. I have tried to draw this but the output shows wrong. Please help me to find out the error.

```html
<table height="600" width="800" border="1" align="center">
  <tr height="350">
    <td width="200" align="center"> Logo </td>
    <td width="200" align="center"> Photo </td>
    <td width="200" align="center"> Info </td>
    <td width="200" align="center"> Gpa </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="250">
    <td width="225" align="center"> Subject </td>
    <td width="200" align="center"> 1st </td>
    <td width="200" align="center"> 2nd </td>
    <td width="175" align="center"> 3rd </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: If your columns must be mismatched, why not make two seperate tables?

Comment: this is clear not what table are meant for

Comment: The second row : 1st cell 225px , 2nd cell 200px, 3rd cell 200px and 4th cell 175px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the table to look like that, here's some code for you. I basically separated your table in two, gave each only half the height (300 instead of 600) and styled the borders accordingly.

```
<table height="300" width="800" align="center" style="border: 1px solid #333;">
    <tbody>
    <tr height="350">
    <td width="200" align="center" style="border-right: 1px solid #333;">Logo</td>
    <td width="200" align="center" style="border-right: 1px solid #333;">Photo</td>
    <td width="200" align="center" style="border-right: 1px solid #333;">Info</td>
    <td width="200" align="center">Gpa</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table height="300" width="800" align="center" style="border: 1px solid #333; border-top: 0;">
    <tbody>
    <tr height="250">
    <td width="225" align="center" style="border-right: 1px solid #333;">Subject</td>
    <td width="200" align="center" style="border-right: 1px solid #333;">1st</td>
    <td width="200" align="center" style="border-right: 1px solid #333;">2nd</td>
    <td width="175" align="center">3rd</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```